# I need a list of linux-image names

Tags: boot, kernel

I've update to *linux-image-3.2.0-30-generic-pae 3.2.0-30.48* and now Ubuntu don't open smoothly and take time to boot but it's not that weird because I had this problem when I was using 11.10 all the time but some how when I upgrade to *12.10* it fixed, so now after I got like 3 new kernel images update the problem got to back again, what I'm asking here is how to bring back the old linux-image to system and you must know I have remove all the old kernels with *Ubuntu Tweak* janitor option so now only one I got is *linux-image-3.2.0-30-generic-pae 3.2.0-30.48*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install the Linux images again

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.2.0-23-generic-pae linux-headers-3.2.0-23 linux-headers-3.2.0-23-generic-pae
```

You should now have option for booting the previous Linux image. Boot to that image and remove the updated one.

If you really want to get a list of all Linux images, You can check the repository pool by [going here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/)

A screenshot is added below:

[image]

Comment: but I already have 3.2.0-30!? and I can't booting the previous Linux image because I've remove them all with Ubuntu Tweak janitor!

Comment: what were the previous versions. replace the version number in the command

Comment: that why I've asked for "a list of linux-image names" the title.

Comment: For a list, go to this link http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-image